# Update VBA code when target value change derives from a formula

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to find a solution that I can adapt to my problem for over a week but as yet I am unable to.

I have 2 combo boxes that change the data in the forecast table.the amount of rows of data vary depending on the selection.

The vba code below allows me to hide rows of a forecast table depending on the value in A1. The value in A1 shows the number of data rows that will be in the table and this derives from a countifs formula.

this code only works when i enter a value into A1 manually, what i need is a way to get this to work when the formula changes the value in A1. I have tried change worksheet and cannot find a soluiton.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
      Rows("8:13").Hidden = False
      If Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value < 5 Then
         Rows(Target.Value + 8 & ":13").Hidden = True
      End If
   End If
End Sub
```

I am hoping someone can help.

I have an example sheet that can be used, but I do not know how to upload file.

Comment: [`Worksheet_Calculate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.calculate(even)).

Comment: I have too many formulas in the sheet, it crashes when I try this